# Correct use of Though

Tags: grammar, writing-style

Is it correct or acceptable to begin a sentence with "though" followed by a comma?
By that, I mean something like "Though, I like red." Is that usage acceptable, and is "though" always preferred to be part of a subordinate clause and not the main one?

Comment: Do you have an actual usage you have in mind besides *Though, I like red?* Because, you know, punctuation depends on context. Some things will work in some contexts, but be questionable or not preferred in other contexts. Four words is hardly enough to go by. As you will see...

Answer (score 1):

'Though' can be used to start a sentence, however the usage you have given isn't really acceptable because at the start of a sentence, 'though' usually operates as a conjunction and you haven't given another clause to be connected to 'I like red'.  Though this is not correct, it would be acceptable if you added a section, eg:

```
Though I like red, my favourite colour is actually blue.
```

Here the though is being used to connect the sentence, despite the fact it is at the  start of a sentence.  The word 'Although' is also interchangeable in this usage.

For more reading and examples, see:
http://grammarist.com/usage/although-though/

Comment: I think the OP means when you use "though" effectively to mean "that said". For example: "My favourite colour is blue. Though, I like red too."

Comment: Well, these should be more connected.  Probably more like: "My favourite colour is blue; though, I like red to."

But even so, that seems very forced and unnatural to me.  It might be just me, but I think that: "My favourite colour is blue, though I like red." seems more usual.

Comment: Thanks you guys. So from what I got, it's not okay to begin a sentence with "though" without it being subordinate to another clause, right?

Comment: @davecw It seems to me you're just talking about a typographical preference (and one essentially irrelevant to the spoken language, of course).

Comment: However, the same way @neilcoffey said in their first comment, you would say 'I like red, though.' In this case *though* is not replaceable with *although*, so that you can move backward that *though* and can write 'Though, I like red' without changing in meaning.